# Where can I find gene expression data on one of the cell lines in NCI-60?

Tags: gene, drugs, cell-line

I'm trying to retrieve the most expressed genes from a cell line from the NCI-60, lets say cell line NCI-H23, but I'm not sure where to find the gene expression data. My main goal is to create a network using that data and iRefIndex to be loaded into Cytoscape. Does anyone know where I can find the correct data or guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

[CellMiner](https://discover.nci.nih.gov/cellminer/) portal has plenty of data about NCI-60 cell lines, inclusive microarray gene-expression.

Also, NCI-60 is a subset of the ~1000 cell lines covered by the [GDSC project](http://www.cancerrxgene.org/downloads) for which you have multiple types of measurements (e.g. copy-number, mutation, gene-expression).

Answer (score 2):

[Cosmic Cell Lines Project](http://cancer.sanger.ac.uk/cell_lines/download) provides gene expression data for 1000+ cell lines (including NCI-60 panel together with NCI-H23 cell line). For each gene in a cell line, you can get Z-score and over/under-expression status calculated across all tumor samples diploid for that gene.